# Load all columns of related table | Flask-SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I have following Flask-SqlAlchemy schema. A Territory can have multiple AsmStores associated with it and I want to load all the columns of related entity (AsmStore) when I query for Territory. I have tried to configure the relationship loading using many approaches but none seems to have work. I always get just the related store IDs and no other attribute as given below in the resultant JSON.

```
class AsmStore(Model):
      __tablename__ = "asmstore"
      id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
      name = db.Column(db.String(255))
      storelatitude = db.Column(db.String(255))
      storelongitude = db.Column(db.String(255))
      territoryid = db.Column(
            db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("territory.id"), nullable=False
      )


class Territory(Model):
      __tablename__ = "territory"

      id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
      name = db.Column(db.String(255))
      centrallatitude = db.Column(db.String(255))
      centrallongitude = db.Column(db.String(255))
      depotlatitude = db.Column(db.String(255))
      depotlongitude = db.Column(db.String(255))
      ideallatitude = db.Column(db.String(255))
      ideallongitude = db.Column(db.String(255))
      areaid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("area.id"), nullable=False)
      storelist = db.relationship("AsmStore", backref="territory")
```

Query:

territory = Territory.query.filter_by(id=territoryid).first()

Resultant JSON:

```
{
"data": {
    "centrallatitude": "",
    "id": 1,
    "storelist": [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10,
        11
    ]
}
```

}

Have I setup the entities incorrectly? If so please advise correction.

Comment: How you generate such JSON?

Comment: Using Flask-Marshmallow.

Comment: I'm using marshmallow (framework-agnostic library for converting python data to JSON). For Flask-Marshmallow you can see docs at https://flask-marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. In clear marshmallow, you have to define another class TerritorySchema which has parent class Schema (which you have to import from marshmallow library). If you want to get an answer for this question please post(edit your question) your Schema definition for each of the above classes.